# Accessing id names in android using loops

Tags: javascript, android

Lets say I have different paragraphs in html with id's like para1, para2 and so on. I can access the elements through the id names in a loop using javascript by enclosing the suffixed numbers in quotes. Can the same be done in android using either java or xml?

For ex. If I had three TextViews in my application with id's text1, text2, text3,
In the regular way, I'd have to do this (in Java):

```
TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
TextView t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
```

So is there any way I can access the id name in a loop using arrays like

```
TextView b[i] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text[i]);
```

or

```
TextView b[i] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text\"i\"); (like in javascript)
```

Comment: paste your xml here.

Answer (score 2):

No, to achieve this you'll have to create an array of ids:

```
@IdRes int[] ids = new int[] { R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3 };

TextView textViews[] = new TextView[3];

for (int i = 0; i < textViews.length; i++) {
    textViews[i] = (TextView) findViewById(ids[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That helps.